# Using sed within "while read" expression

Tags: linux, bash, sed, while-loop

I am pretty stuck with that script.

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTDIR=$1
MNTDIR=/tmp/test/mnt

find $STARTDIR -type l  |
    while read file;
    do
       echo Found symlink file: $file
       DIR=`sed 's|/\w*$||'`
       MKDIR=${MNTDIR}${DIR}
       mkdir -p $MKDIR
       cp -L $file $MKDIR
    done
```

I passing some directory to $1 parameter, this directory have three symbolic links. In while statement echoed only first match, after using **sed** I lost all other matches.
Look for output below:

```
[artyom@LBOX tmp]$ ls -lh /tmp/imp/
total 16K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 artyom adm   19 Aug  8 10:33 ok1 -> /tmp/imp/sym3/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 artyom adm   19 Aug  8 09:19 ok2 -> /tmp/imp/sym2/file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 artyom adm   19 Aug  8 10:32 ok3 -> /tmp/imp/sym3/file3

[artyom@LBOX tmp]$ ./copy.sh /tmp/imp/
Found symlink file: /tmp/imp/ok1
[artyom@LBOX tmp]$
```

Can somebody help with that issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to feed something to sed. Without explicit input, it reads nothing in this construction. I wouldn't use this approach anyway, but just use something like:

```
DIR=`dirname "$file"`
```

Comment: Friek, thanks for robust solution and tip.
From your tip I got this conclusion:
    DIR=`echo $file | sed 's|/\w*$||'`

Comment: That should work indeed. I would stick with the dirname nevertheless.

Comment: @Tom Lime: It's not exactly true that `sed` reads nothing in this case. What it reads is the stdin from where it was called, which in this case is the rest of the stream being piped to `while` (which is why you only get one line of output). Using a subshell with sed (or, worse, `echo | sed`) is hugely overkill. If you don't have `dirname` as Friek recommends then you can say `DIR="${file##*/}"`.